# Can a CSS @container query work based on dynamic content height?

Tags: css, container-queries

I'm trying to change styles of a popup when it is forced above a certain height by its content. I can do this with JS but I'm exploring the new CSS `@container` queries to make it work.

In the example below, I can make the bold tag turn red by adding an explicit height of 50px onto the container. This is good, but I expected this to happen dynamically based on the height of the content. **Is this possible? What's the purpose of container queries if not this?**

Secondly, I want the container background to automatically turn yellow when the longer content is loaded. This does not seem to be possible.
**Is there any way to restyle the *container itself* within a container query?**

```js
//Toggles between long and short content in the div:
var i=1
setInterval(function(){
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = i ? "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Vel nihil optio est dolor earum non explicabo ducimus. Qui fuga sunt quo nemo veritatis ad eaque animi. Id quis quisquam et sequi repudiandae ea deserunt vero sed aliquam eligendi non culpa quos. Vel vitae impedit aut corrupti quisquam ab molestias veritatis qui earum odio! Sit quaerat dolores 33 omnis laboriosam est labore quod." : "Short <b>content</b>"
  i=!i
},1000)
```

```css
#container{ 
  background:#DDD; 
  padding:50px; 
  border-radius:500px; 
  width:300px;
  container: pillPop / size;
}

@container pillPop (min-height: 50px){
    #container{background:yellow;}
    b{color:red}
}
```

```html
<div id='container'> Short <b>content</b> </div>
```

Comment: _"This is good, but I expected this to happen dynamically based on the height of the content."_ - notice how the container doesn't actually grow in your example, when you add the "long" innerHTML ...? Instead, the text content overflows. And your initial, shorter content, did not influence the height of the container either. This appears to be the result of adding `container: pillPop / size;` in the first place. So I am guessing this is some limitation in the specification, to avoid creating unsolvable "catch-22" situations.

Comment: Yes adding the `size` value on the container seems to change the display property somehow. `inline-size` maintains normal functionality but does not make the bold tag red.

Comment: Then this is probably limited in some way, by the spec. Imagine if your short content had a padding-top that was enough to "lift" the container height above the required minimum of the container query, and then inside the container query you removed that padding, so that the height falls below the threshold again ... we'd end up with something flickering quite hectically.

Comment: Of course such situations could possibly also arise in the width "dimension" - but that is probably less like, because the way web pages usually work, the width is more or less a "fixed" dimension, whereas height is almost always dependent on how the content flows & breaks.

Comment: I don't know where the spec says it, specifically, but MDN's [container-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container-type) page says "*Size containment turns off the ability of an element to get size information from its contents, which is important for container queries to avoid infinite loops.*" so I don't think you can do this with container queries.

Comment: @TylerH - Spec is [Sizing as if empty](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-2/#sizing-as-if-empty)

Comment: The answer to your question is no but check the duplicate if you want ideas on how to adjust the color based on the height without container queries